# ViewPager and Toast

Tags: android, android-viewpager, toast

I have a `ViewPager` that loads images from a remote server. My problem is, I don't know how to give it a function once a specific position is selected (not clicked). Let's say, I swipe the view pager until it reaches the specific image like image number 5, I want to show some Toast saying "image 5".

```
pager.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {  





 public class ImagePagerActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private ViewPager pager;

    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_pager);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
    int pagerPosition = bundle.getInt(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
                .build();

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(imageUrls));
    pager.setCurrentItem(pagerPosition);

    }

    protected void onStop() {
    imageLoader.stop();
    super.onStop();
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private String[] images;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImagePagerAdapter(String[] images) {
    this.images = images;
    inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    public void finishUpdate(View container) {
    }

    public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
                final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, null);
                final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
                final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

    imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {

    public void onLoadingStarted() {
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    public void onLoadingFailed(FailReason failReason) {
    String message = null;
    switch (failReason) {
    case IO_ERROR:
    message = "Input/Output error";
    break;
    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
    message = "Out Of Memory error";
    break;
    case UNKNOWN:
    message = "Unknown error";
    break;
    }
    Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
                    }


    public void onLoadingComplete(Bitmap loadedImage) {
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ImagePagerActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
    imageView.setAnimation(anim);
    anim.start();
    }

    public void onLoadingCancelled() {
    // Do nothing
    }
    });

    ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
    return imageLayout;
    }

    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
    }

    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }
    public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
    }

    public void startUpdate(View container) {
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `onPageChangeListener`,  Than you can set this pageChageListener to your ViewPager using (`setOnPageChangeListener()`) ...

```
public class ImagePagerActivity extends BaseActivity implements onPageChangeListener {
    private ViewPager pager;
    // other variables here

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // create view Pager 
        // other variables 
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    // methods for Page Change Listener
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
        if (pos==5) {
          //show Toast here 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // do Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // do Noting
    }

}// class def ends here
```

**edit..**

Use this short hand version

```
Pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        if (pos==5) {
            //show Toast here 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Overridee3public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to use the "setOnPageChangeListener()" but it is giving me an error, it says "The method setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) in the type ViewPager is not applicable for the arguments (ImagePagerActivity)"

Comment: You need to call it using viewPager instance... i.e. viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener() ...

Comment: where you have implemented OnPageChangeListener...  You need to pass that reference to setOnPageChangeListener()...  Implement the interface to ImagePagerActivity. Override the methods as suggested and it will work.

Comment: I am actually lost, can you add it on my code if you don't mind

Comment: I get the same error it says "The method setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) in the type ViewPager is not applicable for the arguments (ImagePagerActivity) "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17919/discussion-between-amit-and-kuwame-brown)

Comment: try the the short code I just added.. If this is not working than there is some serious problem

Comment: any one tell me? how to show toast msg in viewpager like this - > 1/5 ,  means get current position and total no. of images fetches ... like instagram??

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html).

There is as `onPageSelected(int position)` method that you can use to get the current position.

Something like

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Then make your `ImagePagerActivity` implement the `OnPageChangeListener` interface :

```
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
}

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
}
```